# statistics for data analysis

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I am a last year math student, but I also want to learn a bit of data analysis in its theoretical aspect, many have told me that certain bases in statistics are needed, but I have only seen the course of probability and measurement theory Then I would like you to recommend a statistics book for data analysis

I want to clarify that I do not have solid knowledge in statistics, I only have knowledge in probability

Comment: What exactly in data analysis do you want to know? It's kinda a broad field.

Comment: I just want to know a statistics book to be able to have bases to learn data analysis

Comment: Statistics is a broad area, and your question vague, but: the textbook by Freedman, Pisani, and Purves can be read with profit by anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have some background in probability in the context of measure theory; given that, I would suggest you look at one of:

- Shao, *Mathematical Statistics*
- Keener, *Theoretical Statistics*
- Schervish, *Theory of Statistics*

For a non-measure theoretic treatment:

- Bickel and Doksum, *Mathematical Statistics* (in two volumes)
- Casella and Berger, *Statistical Inference*

You will not only need a course in mathematical statistics, but one in linear models. Given your mathematical background, I would suggest either one of:

- Agresti, *Foundations of Linear and Generalized Linear Models*
- Monahan, *A Primer on Linear Models*
- McCullogh, Searle, and Neuhaus, *Generalized, Linear, and Mixed Models*
- Christiansen, *Plane Answers to Complex Questions*

Mathematical statistics and linear models are the core of almost everything in statistics. Once you've learned the contents of these two subjects, you could consider looking at *Advanced Data Analysis from an Elementary Point of View* by Shalizi, available at [https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/ADAfaEPoV/](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/ADAfaEPoV/).